# SetTimeout not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, settimeout, cleartimeout

This code is running all 21 console logs all at once.  It should, however, run them one at a time at a set interval Any suggestions?

```
var index = 1;
var switchBG = function(num){
    if( num < 22 ){
        console.log('index' + index);
        console.log('num' + num);
        index++;
        function_timer(index);
    }
};

var timer;
var function_timer = function(index){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(switchBG(index), 10000);

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a function as an argument to `setTimeout`. Try this:

```
timer = setTimeout(function() {
    switchBG(index);
}, 10000);
```

Doing `setTimeout(switchBG(index), 10000);` basically evaluates `switchBG(index)` and passes its return value (which is currently `undefined`) to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
setTimeout(switchBG(index), 10000);
```

you are calling `switchBG(index)` immediately, and then passing it's return value (which is `undefined`) to `setTimeout`. Instead you want to pass a function reference, and then pass the additional arguments to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(switchBG, 10000, index);
```

If you want to use additional arguments to `setTimeout` like that to work in Internet Explorer, you'll need to [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Callback_arguments) it. It will work in every other browser without a shim.

If you want to support IE and don't want to use the shim, you can create an extra anonymous function to achieve the same result:

```
setTimeout(function(){ switchBG(index); }, 10000);
```